# Need an Inner Query to add up the number of answers inside all questions of a forum

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a forum application with three tables: tbForum, tbQuestion, tbAnswer. With the below query I can successfully add up all the questions inside a forum using an inner query but now I need to find out the number of answers inside each forum, but not sure the best way to do this. Here's an example of the structure:

```
tbForum
ForumID     Name
1           ForumOne
2           ForumTwo
3           ForumThree

tbQuestion
QuestionID     ForumID    QuestionValue
1              1          Why is the sky blue?
2              1          Which way is up?
3              2          How do I do things?

tbAnswer
AnswerID  QuestionID   AnswerValue
1         1            Because water from ocean makes it blue
2         1            Atmosphere stuff
3         1            Blue birds make it blue
4         1            Thats a dumb question
5         2            The top is up.
6         2            That way is up.
7         2            Great question not sure.
8         3            You just do them.
```

I need a query that will return a row called AnswerCount where Answer count for ForumOne is 7 and ForumTwo is 1. AnswerCount for ForumOne is added up because there are two questions in ForumOne (Why is sky blue?, Which way is up?) and there are 7 answers to those questions.

Here's the query that is returning the row QuestionCount correctly. I would probably put the AnswerCount inner query below it, right?

```
select  tbForum.ForumID, tbForum.ForumName, tbQuestion.QuestionID, tbQuestion.QuestionValue,
 (SELECT Count(tbQuestion.ForumID)
  FROM tbQuestion
  WHERE tbForum.ForumID = tbQuestion.ForumID) AS QuestionCount
-- I think I put a similar inner query here, right?!
from tbForum JOIN tbQuestion ON tbForum.ForumID = tbQuestion.ForumID
```

Maybe I need more coffee. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just join all three tables together, group by the required Forum columns, and use the COUNT aggregate to do the accumulation:

```
SELECT  f.ForumID, f.Name, 
        COUNT(DISTINCT q.QuestionID) AS QuestionCount, 
        COUNT(a.AnswerID) as AnswerCount
FROM Forum f 
INNER JOIN Question q ON f.ForumID = q.ForumID
INNER JOIN Answer a ON a.QuestionId = q.QuestionID
GROUP BY f.ForumID, f.Name;
```

[SqlFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9f92f/4)